# array comparision in oracle to get the difference between two arrays

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 arrays with 10 values in each array.
i want to compare the two arrays for finding the difference between column values and print difference columns with old value and new value and store the results in third array.
How i can do that in oracle.

```
DECLARE**strong text**
TYPE array_t is v_array(20) of table%rowtype;
array_diff1 array_t := array_t();
array_diff2 array_t := array_t();
array_diff3 array_t := array_t();

BEGIN
    select * into array_diff1 from table where id =20;
    select * into array_diff2 from table where id =30;
    for i in  array_diff1 
        loop
        for j in array_diff2
        loop
            if array_diff1(i) != array_diif2(j) then
                DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('are not equal');
                **##get the column with the value in array_diff3.**
            else
                DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('are equal');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Everything is here for your question with an example. Please read. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i36377

Comment: Instead of array you can use nested table to leverage multiset operators, with that you can easily find the differences.

Comment: You say you want to store differences - "old" and "new" values - in the third array. That means  the third array needs a different structure. It also means your program needs to have a semantic understanding of the data structures: it needs to know that when there are differences between `array_1(i).whatever` and  `array_2(i).whatever` their respective values go in `array_3(i).old_whatever` and  `array_3(i).new_whatever` .

Comment: Also the datatype is `varray` not `v_array.`

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use any loops, you can do it directly:

```
if array_diff1 <> array_diff2 then
    array_diff3 := array_diff1 MULTISET EXCEPT array_diff2;
else
    DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('are equal');
end if;
```

Check [Multiset Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF51166) for more details.

Note, elements in nested tables do not have a particular order.
For example `array_t(1,2,3)` is equal to `array_t(3,2,1)` when you compare with `=` or `<>`, resp. `!=` (unlike your loop does, unless you order the elements)

Apart from that your code same several syntax errors. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE
TYPE array_t is TABLE of table%rowtype;
array_diff1 array_t := array_t();
array_diff2 array_t := array_t();
array_diff3 array_t := array_t();

BEGIN
    select * BULK COLLECT into array_diff1 from table where id =20;
    select * BULK COLLECT into array_diff2 from table where id =30;

    if array_diff1 <> array_diff2 then
        array_diff3 := array_diff1 MULTISET EXCEPT array_diff2;
    else
        DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE('are equal');
    end if;

END;
```

Comment: I think the OP means to use VARRAY collection. If so order of entries would be preserved (unlike nested tables).

Comment: @APC, yes you are right. But the requirements are not clearly expressed  in the question. I think the mayor point is to use Multiset Operator rather than manual loops.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Not only the columns but also i want to compare column values and save results like colname:value(old and new).